# Loading multiple rdf concurrently as seperate instances in apache jena fuseki server

Tags: sparql, rdf, fuseki, apache-jena, turtle-rdf

I am loading rdf data in ttl format using the command

```
/home/user/jena-fuseki-1.1.1/./s-put http://192.168.1.38:3030/ds/data default /home/user/data.ttl
```

This will replace the ttl file each time a new request comes. How to make it work for multiple users using seperate ttl file concurrently.

What is the **default** argument in the code ? I s there some configuration to make this work. I cannot use an s-post command either as it will append to the existing data. But i need a fresh data loaded concurrently for each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default` means the action is on the default (unnamed) graph in the dataset.